# Find a given string in given path

Tags: haskell

As title states, I am trying to find a given string within a given path. Here is what I come up so far:

```
getRecursiveContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getRecursiveContents topdir = do
  names <- getDirectoryContents topdir
  let properNames = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) names
  paths <- forM properNames $ \name -> do
    let path = topdir </> name
    isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist path
    if isDirectory
      then getRecursiveContents path
    else return [path]
  return (concat paths)

findInFile:: String -> FilePath -> IO Bool
findInFile needle filePath= do
  content <- readFile filePath
  return (needle `L.isInfixOf` content)

findInFolder:: (String -> Bool) -> FilePath -> String -> IO [IO Bool]
findInFolder p path needle = do
  files <- getRecursiveContents path
  return (map (findInFile needle) (filter p files))

find = findInFolder (\p -> takeExtension p `elem` [".py", ".xml", ".html"])
```

I can :

```
*Main> findInFile "search_string" "./path/to/a/file"
True
```

Which is perfect but I cannot do the same search for a folder:

```
*Main> find "./path/to/a/folder" "search_string"
*Main>
```

In my file system `./path/to/a/file` is located under `./path/to/a/folder`. Thus I was expecting the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: `getRecursiveContents` is from [real world haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does indeed work. The only issue is with how things are printed. When you type some expressions into  ghci, it will call `print` on that expression. If the value has type `IO x`, it will execute the `IO` action and print `x` *only if* it has a `Show` instance; otherwise it prints no additional information. 
`find "./path/to/a/folder" "search_string"` produces a list of `IO` actions, which have no `Show` instance. You can get the result of `find`, which is again a list of IO actions, and then execute them:

```
> x <- find "./path/to/a/folder" "search_string"
> sequence x
> [True, False ...
```

Likely you wanted to do this originally in your function. Simply make the following changes:

```
findInFolder:: (String -> Bool) -> FilePath -> String -> IO [Bool]
findInFolder p path needle = do
  files <- getRecursiveContents path
  mapM (findInFile needle) (filter p files)
```

Now `findInFolder` will work as you expect.